XmlValueOutOfRangeException when trying to open Apache POI XSSFWorkbook
I am trying to open an XSSF workbook using the standard method from the guides. However, upon loading, I encounter an error: XmlValueOutOfRangeException: Invalid double value.
Based on the call stack, it appears that the constructor is attempting to read the width of one of the columns and encounters a number it cannot process. However, I do not particularly need the column width information.
If I manually change the column widths in Excel, the error disappears, but this is not a viable solution. What can be done to resolve this issue?
Using default way to initialize workbook from docs
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(fileInputStream);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
   ...
pkg.close()


and getting this
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: Invalid double value: 20,714285714285715
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase$ValueOutOfRangeValidationContext.invalid(XmlObjectBase.java:328) ~[xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaDoubleHolder.validateLexical(JavaDoubleHolder.java:63) ~[xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaDoubleHolder.set_text(JavaDoubleHolder.java:53) ~[xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.update_from_wscanon_text(XmlObjectBase.java:1180) ~[xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_dated(XmlObjectBase.java:1319) ~[xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaDoubleHolder.getDoubleValue(JavaDoubleHolder.java:75) ~[xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColImpl.getWidth(Unknown Source) ~[ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.setColumnAttributes(ColumnHelper.java:254) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.cloneCol(ColumnHelper.java:165) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.addCleanColIntoCols(ColumnHelper.java:85) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.cleanColumns(ColumnHelper.java:57) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.<init>(ColumnHelper.java:46) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:232) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:218) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:454) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:419) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:288) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]


I can't reproduce this with v5.3.0.
